# Magento 2 - controller block not displaying template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, custom-block

I want my module controller to show content inside of store layout (eg show header, then my controller data, then footer, so it will look like being part of the store, not on a blank page). I created a block with template to achieve this, but I didn't made it working.

I wanted to be sure I did everything right, so I used mage2gen to make a test module

> https://mage2gen.com/load/9e9a75ed-e70f-4438-87fc-fce992cc07a0

and I have the same results. When I open the controller url, store header and footer is shown, but the inner part is blank - everything inside template file is ignored.
First I thought it's just not displayed, so I waited for the page to finish loading and then searched the for some text from the template in page source (developer tools -> elements), but it's not here. Like if the template was blank.

I runned magento **`setup:upgrade`** and **`cache:flush`** multiple times, but no changes. The `var/log` has nothing related in here (only debug.log is printing cache_invalidate as always)

**What is wrong here? Did I messed up my store, or is mage2gen not working properly?**

Comment: can you please enter template file code and location? Also did you run `static-content:deploy` command?

Comment: You can see all the code if you visit the mage2gen link, in the right column you can click on them to see content.
Runnin `static-content:deploy` causes an error:  `There are no commands defined in the "static-content" namespace.  Did you mean this?      setup:static-content`
I have store in developer mode, maybe it could be because of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue is layout file name.

Please make it lower case and run all command again. Make sure to flush cache.

```
testmodulblock_index_index.xml
```

Let me know if it works.